# perl match function for C program

Tags: perl

Trying to use perl API functions in C program.  Couldn't find the function to do regular expression match. Wish there is a function like regexmatch in the following program.

```
#include <EXTERN.h>               /* from the Perl distribution     */
#include <perl.h>                 /* from the Perl distribution     */
#include <sys/time.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;  /***    The Perl interpreter    ***/


int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
    int numOfArgs = 0;
    PERL_SYS_INIT3(&numOfArgs, NULL, NULL);
    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct(my_perl);
    SV* str = newSVpv(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    if (regexmatch(str, "/hi (\S+)/")) {
        printf("found a match\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I know it's possible to use pcre library, just wonder if it's possible to get it from perl library here (libperl.so.5.14.2 on ubuntu 12.04)

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:
Did some google search and got the following simple program compiling.  But when I ran the program as `./a.out ping pin`,  it gave "Segmentation fault" in the "pregcomp" function.   Not sure why.

```
#include <EXTERN.h>               /* from the Perl distribution     */
#include <perl.h>                 /* from the Perl distribution     */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <embed.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;  /***    The Perl interpreter    ***/

struct REGEXP * const engine;

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
    int numOfArgs = 0;
    PERL_SYS_INIT3(&numOfArgs, NULL, NULL);
    my_perl = perl_alloc();
    perl_construct(my_perl);

    SV* reStr = newSVpv(argv[2], strlen(argv[2]));
    printf("compiling regexp\n");
    REGEXP * const compiled_regex = pregcomp(reStr, 0);
    printf("execing regexp\n");
    int len = strlen(argv[1]);
    pregexec(compiled_regex, argv[1], argv[1] + len, argv[1], 5, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would say to look at [perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html#REGEXP-Functions) but the regex functions are not documented.

Comment: Using Perl regular expressions from C is very poorly documented.  The best "reference" I can find is `callregexec` in [XS::APItest](https://metacpan.org/source/SHAY/perl-5.20.2/ext/XS-APItest/APItest.xs) but that doesn't cover compiling regexes. Otherwise poke through pp_match in pp_hot.c

Comment: Thanks @Schern for the references. They don't have the "API" I was looking for but they are interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mess with Perl's private internals. Call a Perl sub that uses the match operator.

Say you previously compiled the following in your interpreter (using `eval_pv`),

```
sub regex_match { $_[0] =~ $_[1] }
```

Then you can call

```
static bool regex_match_sv(SV* str, SV* re) {
    dSP;
    bool matched;
    ENTER;
    SAVETMPS;
    PUSHMARK(SP);
    XPUSHs(str);
    XPUSHs(re);
    PUTBACK;
    call_pv("regex_match", G_SCALAR);
    SPAGAIN;
    matched = SvTRUE(POPs);
    PUTBACK;
    FREETMPS;
    LEAVE;
    return matched;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ikegami for the code. It could be a workaround.  I am a little concerned the performance though. Hope there is an easy and fast solution on this.

Comment: It's not a workaround; if you want to call a Perl operator, you need to have a Perl operator, so you need to have Perl code. And if you start talking of the performance penalty of calling a function, your doing something wrong

Comment: I need to access the function(s) that perl uses to do regexp match in my C program.  I am not doing it wrong, I simply don't khow how to do it yet :-)

Comment: None of that is true. Perl doesn't use any regexp library. Perl has a regexp engine functions, and it's exposed as operators to Perl code. You can very well use that; there is no need to mess with Perl's private internals to avoid a sub call.

Comment: I accept this answer as the best but still concerned by the overhead it incurred. May have to use pcre library then.  Thanks again.

Comment: Again, it's rather ludicrous to be concerned about doing `sub foo { bar() } foo();` instead of `bar();`

Comment: @ikegami Perl functions have a significant overhead especially if you're writing C.

Comment: @Schwern, False dychotomy. He's not writing C

Comment: A day late and a dollar short, but I like @ikegami's solution. You only perl compile (i.e. eval_pv) "regex_match" once, then execute it repeatedly. Maybe there's some way to only look up "regex_match" once and pass the function reference directly, but perl is pretty darned quick, and very manageable. For bottom line, write a test program in C that does a typical regex operation, and run it a thousand times with both the perl solution here, and the pcre solution. See if there is a significant difference. If so, use the faster one. If not, use the more manageable one.